# Why mysqli_stmt::prepare cannot be catched when return false?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have code like this, and deliberately make the query error :
delete_test.php.

```
<?php
.....

$id = 1;
$sql = "xSELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE 1 AND id =?"; // Adding and an x to make this error
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if(!$stmt->prepare($sql)){ // Line 56
    echo "There is something wrong #1";
    exit();
}else{
   $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
   if(!$stmt->execute()){
       echo "There is something wrong #2";
       exit();
   }
  .....
}
.....
?>
```

When i run the delete_test.php i get this error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'xSELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE 1 AND id =?' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\delete_test.php:56 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\delete_test.php(56): mysqli_stmt->prepare('xSELECT * FROM ...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\delete_test.php on line 56
```

Instead of print this :

```
There is something wrong #1
```

Why the php neglect `echo "There is something wrong #1";` where the line error at that line ?

And how to make `echo "There is something wrong #1";` is printed where the line error at that line ?

Comment: There is not a single reason to print "There is something wrong #1". What is the actual reason you want to catch the error? what you're going to do?

Comment: @YourCommonSense : Actually i want to catch whatever the error stmt-process happened, in order to show the error message in my version. In above case i want to catch the `prepare()` error message and print the message error in my version as `alert()` to user and print the actual message error in `console.log()'.

Comment: @YourCommonSense : By the way, why did you say "There is not a single reason to print 'There is something wrong #1' " ? I thoguht the actual error message said the error on it's if selector line.

Comment: I did say that because printing 'There is something wrong #1' is not helpful at all. It is useless for a site user and it is useless for a site programmer.

Comment: In order to show  the error message in your version you have to define an error handler. It just makes no sense to write two conditional statement per query. And still lose other errors that you didn't add conditionals for.

Comment: Still, sending the error message in console.log() makes absolutely no sense again. You cannot sit at the every console in every browser every user opens your site with

Comment: @YourCommonSense : Usually i use `try{}catch{}` to catch the error whenever error happened in MySQLi. And thanks about your criticism about the erorr message. I just curious why the echo statement isn't shown up, even though `$stmt->prepare()` is false.
Can you tell me why this happened ?

Comment: because it is never executed. And how many try{}catch{} statements do you usually have in your code?

Comment: @YourCommonSense : I only have one block `try{}catch{}`, i put all of mysqli process in it.
I thought if the statement have been executed, it would be `$stmt->execute()` case.

Comment: Why only mysqli process? What about all other processes? What if there is a permission denied or division by zero error? What if there are two mysqli processes in the page? Five? Ten?

Comment: Yes i said i put all of mysqli process in it meaning all of mysqli process in the page. Should i include all of the process (exclude mysqli process too) in `try{}catch{}` block ? I thought i only need to worry so much to mysqli process, instance because the process can be fail whenever server is down.

By the way, about the mysqli_stmt. When is either  `$stmt->prepare()`  or `$stmt->execute()` going false ? because you said `There is something wrong #1` is not shown because `$stmt->prepare` is never executed.

Comment: I never said prepare is never executed. it is echo "There is something wrong #1"; which is never executed. I don't see any reason to take care about mysqli errors and neglect all other errors. Besides, I don't see any meaningful action to be taken in case of error. Hy not just leave errors alone. What is your actual idea of handling an error?

Comment: Basically what I am trying to tell you is written here: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting in two words, error reporting should be uniform and configurable. For all kinds of errors not just one

Comment: @YourCommonSense : Thanks, i will read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't catch exceptions with an if statement!

There is absolutely no reason to wrap each mysqli function call in an `if` statement, even if you were to switch off mysqli error reporting. Mysqli can trigger exceptions like the one you have received, which tell you much more than *"There is something wrong #1"*.

You have 3 lines of code and you turned it into 12 lines of code, and you still haven't wrapped `stmt_init()` or `bind_param()` in an `if` statement. Just stick to simple three lines of prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("xSELECT * FROM tbl_1 WHERE 1 AND id =?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

PHP has built-in error handler, so if an error happens it can either display it to the end-user or log the error in a file on the server. The latter is preferred. If you want to use your own error handler, then you can wrap all PHP code in a try-catch block and use custom logger handle all exceptions and errors. Do not wrap each mysqli call in try-catch!

Comment: Thanks Dharman, you have explained it well to me. Usually i would wrap mysqli process inside `try{}catch{}`. And then i want to test code that i get from YouTube. And then i curious why `There is something wrong #1` is not printed while it's `if` selector is getting false.
Can you please tell me a little bit why this happened ?
By the way you have answered my question.

Comment: When an exception is triggered the code execution stops. The echo statement is never executed. I suppose the YouTube tutorial you watched was really bad quality and it had error reporting silenced.

Comment: Thanks Darman, now i know i should include all fo my MySQLi process into `try{}catch{}` block